# connect mysql database in websever with c# application

Tags: c#, php, mysql

i have a PHP website and MySQL database in same web sever. i wont to connect that MySQL database with c# application. my c# application in run another computer.
how can i connect that MySQL database ?

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!

Comment: You will need the runtime and the .net connector to make this happen. You also might find the workbench (gui tools to manage the server and run queries) to be helpful.

Comment: Start with the [Connector/Net](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/) and go from there.

Comment: if i got it right:
- you don't have access to your database from your  c# app
- the webserver allows only localhost connection to the database
solution:
you could write a web service that exposes the data and the c# application can connect to the web service. Note: if the app has to write to the database i suggesst you get a vps or if the data is not important to check the input that the web service recieves

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you have downloaded and installed the [MySQL Connector/NET](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/6.1.html) from the MySQL official website. In this article, I will use the Connector/NET version 6.1.

Then add MySql.Data namespace in Reference

Then you can use mysql in .net

now create a connection strin like this

```
     class ConnectToMySql{
           private MySqlConnection connection;

         private void Initialize()
         {
         server = "localhost";
         database = "connectcsharptomysql";
         uid = "username";
         password = "password";
         string connectionString;
         connectionString = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE=" + 
         database + ";" + "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";";

         connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
         connection.Open();
      }


}
```

Then

1 Create a MySQL command.
2 Assign a connection and a query to the command. This can be done using the constructor
3 using the Connection and the CommandText methods in the MySqlCommand class.
4 Create a MySqlDataReader object to read the selected records/data.
5 Execute the command.
6 Read the records and display them or store them in a list.
7 Close the data reader.
8 Close the connection.

I tooth this will help full for you . now you can start working on mysql in .NET

Best of luck

Answer (score 0):

you firstly have to add mysql ref to your project:
plz right click on your project and go to the ref part in it
after that try to find mysl.conncetor and tick it
and refresh your project and firstly try to add using mysql.net.client
now you can use data base located in the mysql db from c# coding
be sure you have downloaded both mysql connector and installaton which is about 500 mb files.

```
class ConnectToMySql{
   private MySqlConnection mscon;
   private void Initialize()
   {
     server = "localhost";
     database = "your own database name";
     uid = " your username";
     password = "your password";
     string const;
     connectionString = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE=" + 
     database + ";" + "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";";

     mscon= new MySqlConnection(const);
     mscon.Open();
  }
}
```